# Cant pass database results to my view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I am learning Codeigniter and I want to show data from database to a datatable in my view.

I don't know what to do, I tried to show data from my database into table in view (using datatable).

here is my model:

```
function get_all_tagihan(){
        return $this->db->query("
            SELECT * FROM tagihan
            WHERE tagihan.TAGIHAN_ISDELETED=0
            ORDER BY tagihan.TAGIHAN_ID;
        ");
    }
```

and here is my controller:

```
public function gettagihan(){

        $this->load->model('model_tagihan');
        $res=$this->model_tagihan->get_all_tagihan();
        $data_tagihan['tagihan']=$res;
        $this->load->view('monitoring/kosong', $data_tagihan);

    }
```

and here my view:

```
<table id="table1" class="table striped hovered cell-hovered border bordered" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td><b>Tarif</b></td>
            <td><b>No. Meter Panel</b></td>
            <td><b>Periode</b></td>
            <td><b>Nama</b></td>
            <td><b>Alamat</b></td>
            <td><b>Unitup</b></td>
            <td><b>Jenis Tarif</b></td>
            <td><b>Daya</b></td>
            <td><b>Nominal PLN</b></td>
            <td><b>Batas Atas</b></td>
            <td><b>Hasil Audit</b></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>



        <?php
        echo"<tbody>";
        if (isset($data_tagihan)){
        foreach ($tagihan as $key) {
            echo"<tr><td>".$key->TARIF_ID."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->PANEL_ID."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_PERIODE."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_NAMA."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_ALAMAT."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_UNITUP."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_JENISTARIF."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_DAYA."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_NOMINALPLN."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_BATASATAS."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$key->HASILAUDIT_ID."</td></tr>";
        }
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It shows the data table, there is no error shown, but why does it keep saying that "No data available in table"? There is already some data in my database.

I have no idea. Do you guys have any suggestions on what I am suppose to do? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to use `result()` after building your query. Remember that this should be in your model method because `$q->result()` is part of your data layer:

```
public function get_all_tagihan(){
    $q = $this->db->query("
                SELECT * FROM tagihan
                WHERE tagihan.TAGIHAN_ISDELETED=0
                ORDER BY tagihan.TAGIHAN_ID;
            ");
    return $q->result();
}
```

Source: [**Generating Query Results in Codeigniter 3**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays)

**Update:**

There's also something wrong in your view (as @blacmoon mentioned):

Every time you send data to your view you do it by assigning an array via your controller and passing it to the view. When you do this, you are sending all the array elements to the view as variables. In other words, **only** the elements of the array are transformed into variables in your view, the actual name of the array is never passed. For example:

if your controller is like this:

```
function test()
{
    $data = array(
        "parent_name" => "John",
        "parent_age" => 52,
        "children" => array(
            array(
                "name" => "Jane",
                "age" => 22,
            )
        )
    );
    $this->load->view('test', $data);
}
```

your view will only receive the following variables:

```
$parent_name = "John";
$parent_age = 52;
$parent_children = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Jane",
        "age" => 22,
    )
);
```

As you can see the variable `$data` is never passed and therefore does not exist in the view.

In your case, you set the array `$data_tagihan` in this manner:

```
$res = $this->model_tagihan->get_all_tagihan();
$data_tagihan['tagihan'] = $res;
$this->load->view('monitoring/kosong', $data_tagihan);
```

and then check it in your view like this:

```
 if (isset($data_tagihan)){
```

This is wrong because `$data_tagihan` will never exist. However `$tagihan` does exist. Therefore your conditional should be like this:

```
 //empty() is best used because it checks if its set, and if it has contents
 if (!empty($tagihan)){
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in view:
change this  if (isset($data_tagihan)){  

-- > if(!empty($tagihan)){

Comment: OMG, It really helpful! Thanks anyone! :D

Answer (score 0):

In your model....

```
function get_all_tagihan()
{
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tagihan WHERE tagihan.TAGIHAN_ISDELETED = 0 ORDER BY tagihan.TAGIHAN_ID;")->result();
}
```

And finally in view...

```
if (count($tagihan) > 0 )
{
    foreach ($tagihan as $key) 
    {
        echo"<tr><td>".$key->TARIF_ID."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->PANEL_ID."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_PERIODE."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_NAMA."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_ALAMAT."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_UNITUP."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_JENISTARIF."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_DAYA."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_NOMINALPLN."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->TAGIHAN_BATASATAS."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$key->HASILAUDIT_ID."</td></tr>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "no data in table";
}
```

Comment: even though, this would work, it is wrong because `result()` should be placed in the model, as it is the data layer. By doing it this way, you are breaking the MVC structure.

Comment: I was gonna edit it but forgot thanks for remind me this... :)